# Why does "Xperia Keyboard" use up mobile traffic?

Tags: mobile-data, sony-xperia-s

I checked Settings->Data Usage, and an app called "Xperia Keyboard" has used up 513 KB of mobile traffic.

Why would the keyboard app need to use 513 KB of mobile data? It's a keyboard app, why does it need an internet connection at all?

Comment: Community shared dictionary for spell-checking maybe? Just a guess, I don't know.

Comment: Is there an option to turn of data for that keyboard app?